# Borel structure on Grothendieck topology, sort of ...

Tags: measure-theory, category-theory, grothendieck-topologies

Given a usual topological space $X$ we define in a natural way the Borel algebra $\mathcal{B}(X)$, i.e., the smallest algebra (or $\sigma$-algebra) of subsets of $X$ containing all open subsets of $X$. This makes $X$ a measurable space, which is very convenient.

Now let $X$ be an object in a category, equipped with a Grothendieck topology. I am only starting to learn this thing, so for me this is basically replacing subsets with inclusion maps. Unions and intersections can be made sense of as pullbacks/pushouts of monic morphisms, and complement of $A$ in $X$ can probably be thought of as a universal subset $B$ such that $A\cup B=X$, if it exists, I don't know.

**Question:** Is there such a thing as Borel algebra on a Grothendieck topology? Can I give a measure space structure to an object of a category beyond the category of sets/spaces?

I have seen a few posts on MSE and MO which go the other way round, i.e., start from a measure space and topologize it etc. That is not what I am interested in.

I am completely illiterate in abstract algebra and category theory, so, please, be forgiving and use as simple arguments and terminology as possible. A positive-ish answer to this question would be a great motivation for me to study the subject properly.

Thank you.

Comment: Your wording is ambiguous, but to be clear, categories can be equipped with Grothendieck topologies, not the objects in them. Also, the name "Grothendieck topology" is a bit misleading as it is not a direct analogue of a topology on a set.

Comment: No. In general the covering maps are not inclusions (not monomorphisms), and I don't think complements should exist in general either.

Comment: user45878, I can restrict my category to monomorphisms only, and consider topologies on the restricted categories. I can agree that complements need not exist in general, but suppose they do. Do I get a $\sigma$-algebra?

Comment: Derek Elkins, I sort of see that this is not exactly a topology. But it still has to do with systems of sets covering the whole, so maybe a perverse notion of $\sigma$-algebra could be found, I thought.

Comment: Note that both the *topology* and the *set of points* are almost completely irrelevant in measure theory. The path I think you want to travel leads to [measurable locales](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/measurable+locale), and  the topos of sheaves on such a locale is interesting.

Comment: I guess that again goes the other direction. I do not want to start from a measurable structure and go to a topology (or a topos). I want to start from a good category and a "topology" on it, and end up with a measurable structure.

Comment: You can pass to the topos of sheaves of sets on your Grothendieck topology, take its coreflection in the subcategory of measurable locales and measurable maps (or rather, their associated toposes and geometric morphisms).  You can then reconstruct a Grothendieck topology from a topos in a standard way.